# In-memory query: DBSet vs ObjectSet

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

In-memory query performed by `DBSet<T>.Local` will also return newly added entities that haven't yet been saved to the database. Is there some functionality that would allow us to perform such an in-memory query on an `ObjectSet` ( BTW - I know we could use `ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries` to get similar results)?

Thank you

Comment: If you voted to close it due to there already being an identical thread, then please post a link to that thread, since I I'm not able to find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Local` is just advanced wrapper (it is `ObservableCollection` with all its benefits) around functionality provided by `ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries`.